# How to paste svg on svg

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, svg

I need to make an image consist of two other SVGs, one as background and the other should be on the background in a certain position.

here is an example:

**background**

[image: background]

**some shape**

[image: background]

**desired result**

[image: background]

I need to set the *shape SVG* position so it'd be possible to use various backgrounds. and if possible changing color of *backgrounds* and *shapes*.
actually, What's the best tool (Python, Nodejs or PHP) to modify SVGs like changing colors, resizing, merging, etc.

Comment: You can change the color of svg elements using css.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a SVG into another SVG as following:

```
<svg>
    <svg>
        [...]
    </svg>
</svg>
```

I hope, this works for you

Comment: thanks, I know that. but I want to do that programmatically, and I have a problem with positioning the shape in the background.